# How do I change an existing srs in QGis?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg, srid

I am showing postgis data with srid 28992 (Amersfoort / RD New). But when I plot the geospatial data on a map (with openlayers plugin), the data is shown a hunderd meters off because the datum shift is not taken into account.

When I make a custom CRS with the correct datum shift and set my layer to that CRS is it shown correctly.

I want to update QGis' standard interpretation of 28992 so it takes into account this datum shift (+towgs84 parameter) correctly and when I open new data it is shown correctly immediately.

I found that QGis has a sqlite db called srs.db in /usr/share/qgis/resources/.  But even when I update the record for 28992 it still doesn't show the data correct on the map. When I inspect the layer in QGis I see it still has no +towgs84 parameter.

Does this mean that QGis does not actually use this sqlite db? Because the data I show is from a postgresql database I also edited spatial_ref_sys.sql to make sure that it also knows about the datum shift.

I also edited the epsg en esri files in /usr/share/proj/ just to be sure, but no effect.

At this moment I cannot think of another place where QGis gets its projection information from.

Comment: related discussion last summer: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SRS-DB-maintenance-td5057450.html

Comment: This discussion talks about the way the srs db is filled. So it kinda suggests it is used, but doesn't explain why my manual update of a record doesn't appear in the front end. Maybe there is some sort of cache somewhere? (i did reboot the machine as extra security)

Comment: more on the issue but without indication if the approach works: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/changing-srs-db-with-coordinate-system-updater-Plugin-td5052833.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your Postgis and QGIS share the same +towgs84 parameters?

My QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour comes with this definition:

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

while my PostgreSQL has this stored in table spatial_ref_sys

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +units=m +no_defs
```

If your QGIS has another proj definition for EPSG:28992, your installation might be broken.
Have a look at the setup log if postinstall was broken somewhere.

One other point: Postgis uses this string for the WKT definition:

```
PROJCS["Amersfoort / RD New",
  GEOGCS["Amersfoort",
    DATUM["Amersfoort",
      SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6289"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4289"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
  PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52.15616055555555],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",5.38763888888889],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999079],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",155000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",463000],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","28992"],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

which references to Amersfoort datum, but no +towgs84 are stored for that. I am not sure if QGIS therefore sets +towgs84 to zero, instead of using its own EPSG values, or those from the Postgis proj4 string.

QGIS writes this .qpj output:

```
PROJCS["Amersfoort / RD New",
  GEOGCS["Amersfoort",
    DATUM["Amersfoort",
      SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
    TOWGS84[565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6289"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4289"]],
PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52.15616055555555],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian",5.38763888888889],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999079],
  PARAMETER["false_easting",155000],
  PARAMETER["false_northing",463000],
  UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
  AXIS["X",EAST],
  AXIS["Y",NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","28992"]]
```

Comment: My QGis Dufour does not have that +towgs parameter. So where does it get its definition from?

Comment: At the end of the setup process, crssync.exe is invoked to synchronize the CRS database with the GDAL definitions. If your setup failed in an earlier step, no synchronizing is done. For the Windows standalone installer, look into postinstall.log, for OSGEO4W in var/log/setuplog.full. If you want to re-run crssync.exe, start the OSGeo4w shell, then qgis.bat insode the shell to have the correct environment set.